# How does Chrome devtools calculate the computed-metric width of an element?

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, width, google-chrome-devtools

I need to know how Chrome gets the "computed-metric" width of an element in the Computed pane of devtools:

[image: Computed Metrics]

Why does it differ from the content width of an element?  You can test this by scrolling to the bottom of the Computed pane and find the "width:" there (notice it reads "267.484375px" and not the reported "237.458"):

[image: The computed-metric width is not consistent with the Computed-'width'-Property]

TO verify these claims you can utilize the jQuery .width() method, which calculates the content width without the padding irrespective of box-sizing property:

```
$(".element_class.to_verify").width();
236.98399925231934
```

Obviously the content width reported by jQuery is a lot different than even the "Computed width Property" reported by Chrome.  SO different it's enough to ruin good designs.. **so how are these "widths" calculated by Chrome** *and why are they not consistent?*

Is it possible there is something wrong with my install or that I'm missing something?

Comment: It's because you are using `box-sizing: border-box` so the width includes the padding. Devtools on the other hand is only showing the different metrics.

Comment: I haven't seen it show decimals at all -- and I would never rely on decimals in pixels either way.

Comment: The `width` obviously does include the padding of 2 x 15px.

Comment: @Hoshts what width are you referring to?

Comment: @Bergi then how do you explain the difference between the Metric and the width that javascript/jquery return (236..)?

Comment: @Johan I agree, but the inconsistency is still disconcerting.  If we can't trust our tools for measuring, then how can we be expected to do do our job? 237.468 is a lot different from 237.484, and again why an entire pixel away from what jQuery deems as it's content Width.

Comment: @u353: Well, jQuery even is *documented* not to consider the `box-sizing` and always return the content width? So why did you think they would need to match in the first place?

Comment: @Bergi Yes I know that I stated it in the question, see?  It's not a difference in box sizing it's off by a pixel, and the decimals are still way off (set aside the idea that decimal placess don't matter, for now).

Comment: @u353 the CSS property width. It change (include the padding) because of the box-sizing:border-box. The metrics shown in devtools and by JS are the real values of the content area without the padding. It's all part of the box model of HTML.

Comment: @Hoshts Thank you for the minimal effort, but you're not telling me anything I haven't already stated in the original post.  Look at the numbers again, the CSS property width is still at least 1 pixel off from the jQuery width(); and there are no borders on this element as you can see.  I am NOT asking about the box-sizing, I already know this and stated it in the question.